# Haskell Type Matching Error in custom data type with List/Tuple Construction

Tags: haskell, custom-data-type

I do not understand why this does not work.
My data type is as follows:

```
data IndexedTree a = Leaf [a] | Node [(IndexedTree a, a)]

first (x, _ ) = x
test :: IndexedTree a -> Bool
test (Leaf x) = True
test (Node (x:xs)) = test first(x)
```

yields to

```
Could not match expected type IndexedTree a0
with actual type (t0,t1)-> t0
```

in the last LOC.
I dont get why this is happening and how to avoid this.

Comment: Note that the `Prelude` function `fst` is identical to your `first`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition of `test` should be:

```
test :: IndexedTree a -> Bool
test (Leaf x) = True
test (Node (x:xs)) = test (first x)
```

`first (x)` is the same as `first x`, and since function application associates to the left

```
test first (x)
```

is parsed as

```
(test first) x
```

`test` expects an `IndexedTree a` argument but `first` has type `(a, b) -> a`, hence the error.

You should also handle the case where the node list is empty.

Answer (score 1):

`first(x)` is the same as `first (x)`, which is the same as `first x`. So `test first(x)` is just `test first x`, and `test` expects only one argument.

If you want to evaluate `first x` first:

```
test (Node (x:xs)) = test $ first x
```